# Choosing among Physical Font and Logical Font

Tags: java, internationalization

In my applicaion which is going to support language other than English, **is there any thing I should take into consideration, whether to choose Physical Font (For example, Times New Roman) or Logical Font (For example, Serif)?**

It is a shame that, only recently, I discover the ability to display non-English characters, is also depeding on the font you are choosing. For example, I explicitly using Tahoma font in my application, and I realize Tahoma doesn't support display Chinese :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical font, unless you know what you are doing (such as, you are writing a graphics editor and the user explicitly chosen the typeface).

That's exactly what logical fonts are for: let the user configuration and other circumstances decide the exact typeface.